# currency.methods.transfer is not a function

Tags: dapps, error

````
   let cost = CONFIG.WEI_COST;
   var _pid = "0";
   let contract = "0x3b85A341F79764821cD5c0672A4fD630c8F0DdA2";
  

   
   var erc20address = await blockchain.smartContract.methods.getCryptotoken(_pid).call();
 
   var currency = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, erc20address);
   var mintRate = await blockchain.smartContract.methods.getNFTCost(_pid).call();
   var _mintAmount = Number(mintAmount);
   var totalAmount = mintRate * _mintAmount;
 
   let gasLimit = CONFIG.GAS_LIMIT;
   let totalCostWei = String(cost * mintAmount );
   let totalGasLimit = String(gasLimit * mintAmount );
   console.log("Cost: ", totalCostWei);
   console.log("Gas limit: ", totalGasLimit);
   setFeedback(`Minting your ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME}...`);
   setClaimingNft(true);

**This is the code giving error**
currency.methods.approve(CONFIG.CONTRACT, String(totalAmount)).send({from: blockchain.account});
   
   blockchain.smartContract.methods
   .then (await currency.methods.transfer
     (CONFIG.CONTRACT, String(totalAmount))
     .send({from: blockchain.account,
       gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit)
     
     },
     async function (error, transactionHash) {
       // console.log("Transfer Submitted, Hash: ", transactionHash)
       let transactionReceipt = null
       while (transactionReceipt == null) {
         transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash);
         await sleep(10000)
       }
   }))

     .mint(_mintAmount, _pid)
     .send({
       gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
       to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
       from: blockchain.account,
       value: totalCostWei,
     }) 


Let _pid = 0;

Blockchain.smartContract.methods
.mint(mintAmount, _pid)
.send ect ```
``` `let web3 = new Web3(ethereum);

   let cost = CONFIG.WEI_COST;
   var _pid = "0";
   let contract = "0x3b85A341F79764821cD5c0672A4fD630c8F0DdA2";
  

   
   var erc20address = await blockchain.smartContract.methods.getCryptotoken(_pid).call();
 
   var currency = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, erc20address);
   var mintRate = await blockchain.smartContract.methods.getNFTCost(_pid).call();
   var _mintAmount = Number(mintAmount);
   var totalAmount = mintRate * _mintAmount;
 
   let gasLimit = CONFIG.GAS_LIMIT;
   let totalCostWei = String(cost * mintAmount );
   let totalGasLimit = String(gasLimit * mintAmount );
   console.log("Cost: ", totalCostWei);
   console.log("Gas limit: ", totalGasLimit);
   setFeedback(`Minting your ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME}...`);
   setClaimingNft(true);
   currency.methods.approve(CONFIG.CONTRACT, String(totalAmount)).send({from: blockchain.account});
   
   blockchain.smartContract.methods
   .then (await currency.methods.transfer
     (CONFIG.CONTRACT, String(totalAmount))
     .send({from: blockchain.account,
       gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit)
     
     },
     async function (error, transactionHash) {
       // console.log("Transfer Submitted, Hash: ", transactionHash)
       let transactionReceipt = null
       while (transactionReceipt == null) {
         transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash);
         await sleep(10000)
       }
   }))

     .mint(_mintAmount, _pid)
     .send({
       gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
       to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
       from: blockchain.account,
       value: totalCostWei,
     }) 




Blockchain.smartContract.methods
.mint(mintAmount, _pid)
.send ```
````

Config.contract is the USDC contract and the abi is the NFT contract

Contract works well, but it pulls up the approve function but than says that it’s not a function and the dapp fails but the metamask pops up with the usdc transaction to approve which makes no sense since the dapp says it’s not a function.